# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Suggestions to store filenames that have different formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I would like suggestions if possible on how to manage/store files that have various formats of file names.

Filename examples:

- field1_field2_field3_field4_field5
- field1_field2_field3
- field1_field2_field3_field4

Currently this is the model that I have

```
public class DocumentCategories
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Delimiter { get; set; }
    public int StructureCount { get; set; }
    public string Structure { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to store the field structure as a JSON into the Structure field and count how many fields there are. I will also store the delimiter into a field. The current rule is that there is only one delimiter per file structure.

When I upload a file, I will count the fields in the filename and then select the correct DocumentCategory and split the fields in the filename and convert them into JSON and store it in another table that has this structure:

```
public class DocumentCategoryLink
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that if I want to search through my table, how do I do it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: One thing i didnt understood do the file looks like field1_field2_field3_field4_field5
.txt . And whats the purpose of the fields? I mean you want to store the field structure, so field structure means field1 , field2, field3? In generall can you be more specific about what you want to achieve. Cause what i read that you want to achieve vs what are you doing are 2 totally different things.

Comment: Oh sorry, so currently this is how I store my filenames. I have a model that can accomodate only one file structure which is name_dob_country_number. The way it gets parsed is when I upload a file, its name gets split with the underscore as a delimiter. 
The issue is that I can only store one file structure type which is name_dob_country_number.

Comment: The intention of the field structures is so that I can match the fields on the filename dynamically. e.g Structure 1 looks like this field1_field2_field3 and File1 looks like this name_country_number. That means each file will be associated with one field structure

Comment: In essence I'm trying to create some form of metadata? that I can use when I want to search for a document.